# Does prior knowledge of the result of certain trials change the overall expected result for all trials in a set?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

For example, if you have a set of 100 coin flips and know that, of the first 20, 16 were heads. Would the overall expected number of heads still be 50 or would it change to 56?

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on the exact wording of the question.

If you ask: I'm going to flip a fair coin 100 times, what is the expected value of heads? The answer is 50.

If you ask: I flipped a fair coin 20 times and 16 were heads. What is the expected value of heads if I flip the coin 80 more times? The answer is $16 + 40 = 56$.

This is assuming you know the coin is fair. If you don't know the fairness of the coin, you'd need a prior on the probability the coin is heads. After observing 16/20 heads you might have a fairly strong belief the coin is biased towards heads and thus would expect to observe an even higher number of heads.

Comment: (+1) Just wanted to highlight that the expected proportion of heads for future flips is *always 50%*. The results of prior flips are irrelevant (except, as you say, in the case that it tells you you have an unfair coin).